# Combining two queries, finding dupes AND IS NULL or empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a single query where it will report back all accounts where the SSN is not null or empty (<> '') AND that the SSN only exists once. (No duplicate SSN).  I have the two queries written correctly, but seperate. Any Idea on how I would combine the two? Here are the following queries:

Find duplicates:

```
SELECT [ContactID]
     , [SSN]
FROM [dbo].[ContactMaster]
GROUP BY [ContactID], [SSN]
HAVING COUNT([SSN]) > 1
```

Here is the second query finding any null or empty SSN:

```
SELECT [SSN] FROM [dbo].[AccountContacts] WHERE [SSN] IS NULL OR [SSN] = ''
```

Any ideas on how I could combine these two into a single query? Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the result? Add sample data, and expected result.

Comment: Sorry, I would like the expected result to just list two columns, contactID (int) and SSN (char(9)).

Comment: Add [ContactID] to your second query (maybe even a description of the issue as a hardcoded piece of text to both queries) then use UNION to bring them together?

Comment: Your first query actually brings back duplicates, not uniques

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION like this:

```
SELECT [ContactID]
     , [SSN]
FROM [dbo].[ContactMaster]
GROUP BY [ContactID], [SSN]
HAVING COUNT([SSN]) > 1

UNION

SELECT [ContactID], [SSN] FROM [dbo].[AccountContacts] WHERE [SSN] IS NULL OR [SSN] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have both a `WHERE` and a `HAVING` clause together in a single query. The `WHERE` is processed before the aggregate processing and the `HAVING` is processed afterwards:

```
SELECT   [ContactID], [SSN]
FROM     [dbo].[ContactMaster]
WHERE    [SSN] IS NULL OR [SSN] = ''
GROUP BY [ContactID], [SSN]
HAVING   COUNT([SSN]) = 1
```

Is it even possible to have empty/NULL `SSN` values in the `ContactManager` table in your database? If it's being used as a foreign key, there might not be any NULL values.